# if(!node) vs if(node == nullptr), any difference?

Tags: c++

As the title says. When checking if a node is `nullptr`, is there any difference between `if(!node)` and `if(node == nullptr)` or are they equivalent (given that `node == NULL` is not equivalent to `node == nullptr`).

Comment: Except style and personal preference? Then no there's no difference. You could build a program which does both, then check the generated assembly to see if there's a difference (remember to always check an optimized builds). The compiler should treat `node == 0`, `node == NULL`, `node == nullptr` and `!node` equal (and keep in mind that the macro `NULL` is most likely expanded to `0`, so the two first are *exactly* same).

Comment: What makes you think `node == NULL` is not equivalent to `node == nullptr`? Since C++11, they are literally identical, with  `NULL` defined via `#define NULL nullptr`. These four functions using `!x`, `x != 0`, `x != NULL` and `x != nullptr` produce identical assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/46cdEse5f

Comment: Your inference that `node == NULL` is not equivalent to `node == nullptr` is incorrect.   When `node` is a pointer and `NULL` a null pointer constant (such as the definition it has in standard headers), they are equivalent.  Use of `nullptr` is more type-safe  (e.g. using `nullptr` where an `int` is expected is a diagnosable error) but that doesn't mean comparisons using them are not equivalent. In any event, where `node` is a pointer, the expressions `!node`, `node == NULL`, and `node == nullptr` all give the same result (a `bool` that is `true` if `node` is a null pointer).

Comment: @user229044 I meant that `NULL` can be used in place of an integer as zero. Hence, they are not equivalent in this particular scenario.

Comment: `given that node == NULL is not equivalent to node == nullptr` is wrong though. They ARE equivalent. Also, `nullptr` can be converted to an integer via: `static_cast<std::intptr_t>(nullptr)` and it would typically produce `0`.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of dupes for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in terms of assembly produced. There is no difference. [See this live example.](https://godbolt.org/z/sMej7dY4s)

In terms of readability, it is an opinion, but the [cppcoreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es87-dont-add-redundant--or--to-conditions)  prefer `if (!node)`:

> ES.87: Don’t add redundant == or != to conditions
>
> Reason: Doing so avoids verbosity and eliminates some opportunities for mistakes. Helps make style consistent and conventional.

The example they give replicates yours very closely:

```
// These all mean "if p is not nullptr"
if (p) { ... }            // good
if (p != 0) { ... }       // redundant !=0, bad: don't use 0 for pointers
if (p != nullptr) { ... } // redundant !=nullptr, not recommended
```

Comment: I usually am very onboard with cpp core guidelines. In this case I actually prefer being explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The generated code should be the same either way.

The primary advantage of `nullptr` is that it can *only* be compared to a pointer, so if (for example) you one variable named `node` and one named `anode`, and your IDE "helps" you by completing `nod` to `anode`, the result won't compile unless `anode` also happens to be a pointer.

By contrast, `if (anode)`, `if (!anode)`, `if (anode == 0)` and `if (anode == NULL)` will all compile for `anode` being quite a few different types (any pointer, integer, floating point, `bool`, non-class enumeration, and a fair number of others).

Comment: Somewhat opposite answers :p